# Bias Variance Decomposition Question

Tags: statistics, regression

> Assume that $(x_1, Y_1), ..., (x_n,Y_n)$ with $Y_i = f(x_i)+
>  \epsilon_i$, $x_i$ and want to predict a new observation $Y_0 = f(x_0)+ \epsilon_0$ with $Var(\epsilon_i) = 1$ and $Var(\epsilon_0) =
>  1$ with $\epsilon_0$ independent of $\epsilon_1, ..., \epsilon_n$.
> Does there exist any estimator $\hat{Y}_0$ which only depends on the
> data $(x_1, Y_1), ..., (x_n,Y_n)$ and satisfies $\mathbb{E}[(\hat{f}(x_0)-Y_0)^2] = \dfrac{1}{2}$? Why or why not?

I am having trouble telling which are fixed and which are random.
Also, any suggestions on how to begin would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: I think the usual convention is to use lower-case for fixed values, and upper-case for random values. So in this case the $x_i$ are fixed and the $Y_i$ are random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Carefully use the assumptions in the problem to show
$$E[(\hat{f}(x_0) - f(x_0))(f(x_0) - Y_0)]=0.$$
Consequently, you can show that your expectation can be decomposed as
$$E[(\hat{f}(x_0)-Y_0)^2] = E[(\hat{f}(x_0) - f(x_0))^2] + E[(f(x_0)-Y_0)^2].$$
Now simplify the second term on the right-hand side.

Comment: Would the second term just simplify to $(f(x_0) - Y_0)^2$ since the inside is fixed?

Comment: $Y_0$ is random @Oran

Comment: Can you explain where your second line came from? Why is it equal to 0?

Comment: @Oran Re-read the problem statement and think about what $\hat{f}$ depends on, what $Y_0$ depends on, and what independence assumptions you have.

Comment: $\hat{f}(x_0)$ is the prediction which depends on $x_0$ and $Y_0 = f(x_0)$ is the actual value we want to predict and it also depends on $x_0$ right? And we only know that $\epsilon_0$ is independent from the rest of the $\epsilon_i$'s.

Comment: @Oran $\hat{f}$ also depends on the data $(x_1, Y_1), \ldots, (x_n, Y_n)$.

Comment: Right, since we are trying to find any estimators $\hat{Y}_0$ that depends on said data. But how does that help?

Comment: @Oran $\hat{f} $ and $Y_0$ are independent, so $E[(\hat{f}(x_0)-f(x_0))(f(x_0)-Y_0)] = E[\hat{f}(x_0)-f(x_0)] \cdot E[f(x_0) - Y_0]$.